# Keep getting a HTTP 504 from SO when running fiddler

Tags: support, http

Is anyone else experiencing this or is it a bug with fiddler? Only seems to of started happening since I upgraded to the latest version of fiddler (v4.4.6.1). It will work fine sometimes but then after a bit I have to close fiddler to vote or comment or any of the async actions on the site.

### Request:

```
POST http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22321578/vote/2 HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://stackoverflow.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321578/asp-net-mvc-angular-js-sorted-and-offset-issue
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Cookie: __qca=P0-1518564088-1367499799852; __utma=140029553.1579756772.1367499800.1389618809.1389623150.765; __utmz=140029553.1389608461.762.37.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); sgt=id=a2d0c1e4-ed74-4171-af8e-a6ce2481bd98; usr=t=xoAWl6L7ECLR&s=3Dzy9zy6QEaC; _ga=GA1.2.1579756772.1367499800

fkey=36a81e10077e5056af22245921553c36
```

### Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Tue, 11 Mar 2014 09:38:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 09:38:59.284

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

[image]

I'm not sure if it's relevant but I'm using Chrome `Version 33.0.1750.146 m`

Comment: No **V4**. The .Net 4 version.

Comment: Wasn't aware that existed. We'll have to wait for someone who runs that one, then :)

Comment: I only tried for a few minutes, but I'm not having trouble voting. Tested with IE 11 and Fiddler 4.4.6.1

Comment: I can confirm this issue, with the exact same version of Chrome, however I've also had the issue on some AJAX requests in my own projects so I put it down to a bug in Fiddler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just noticed there is a [support thread on this on the fiddle google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/httpfiddler/NvmeBsmBaWU). Looks Like Eric has released a fix in `4.4.6.2`:

> ### New Build (resolves HTTP502/504 errors in v2.4.6.1/4.4.6.1)
>
> Fiddler versions 2.4.6.2 & 4.4.6.2 have been released. You can get
>   them using Help > Check for Updates or by visiting
>   http://getfiddler.com
>
> The new builds restore the behavior that allows resubmission of a POST
>   request if the server fails to return a response on a reused
>   connection. That behavior is in violation of the HTTP RFCs, but after
>   watching my inbox catch on fire with complaints this week, it's clear
>   that real-world clients and servers are violating this requirement of
>   the standard constantly, and thus Fiddler now will do so again.
>
> This build also introduces the ability to use whatever icon you want
>   for Fiddler, so folks who prefer an older Fiddler icon or even a
>   different icon entirely may use it. See
>   http://fiddlerbook.com/dl/retrofiddler.zip for a zip file containing
>   the instructions and the 2003, 2008, and 2012 versions of the Fiddler
>   icon.
>
> thanks for using Fiddler, and thanks for letting me know about the
>   issues you've had with build 2.4.6.1.
>
> -Eric